# Borel Cantelli curiosity

Tags: real-analysis, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I’ve been reading the part 2.5 in Royden’s book (Real Analysis) and I’m curious about the Borel-Cantelli Lemma, is it possible to have the inverse implication?

Comment: The second Borel-Cantelli lemma is a partial converse, requiring the additional assumption of independence.

Comment: Like the probabilistic one? In this case it should be disjoint, or am I confused?

Comment: Yes, probabilistic independence, which I’ll grant is not the most natural condition to consider outside the context of probability theory. Disjointness is not analogous to independence.